# UIView .xib buttons not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, xcode6, xib

i have created a UIView .xib with some labels and a button. I connected all the outlets and the IBAction for the button.

When i add the .xib subview from my viewcontroller it shows ok, but the button is not working.

This is my xib´s  .m file

```
-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])
    {
        [self load];
    }
    return self;
}


-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if(self = [super initWithFrame:frame])
    {
        [self load];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)load
{
    [[self superview] setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    UIView *view = [[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]     loadNibNamed:@"AgregarAlCarrito" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
    [self addSubview:view];
    view.frame = self.bounds;
}
```

i have tried everything you can imagine without results

thanks

Comment: Is your .xib having a UIViewController or just a UIView ?

Comment: i was incorrectly creating the .xib object, when i used this method it works ok    NSArray *subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AgregarAlCarrito" owner:self options:nil];
    UIView *mainView = [subviewArray objectAtIndex:0];

Answer (score 0):

So this line looks very suspect to me:

```
[self addSubview:view];
```

You should be adding the xib view to the parent view.  Where I did something like this in one of my apps, I had something like this:

```
[[self view] addSubview:_xibView];
```